# How do I handle a third party API callback in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

**Question**

A NodeJS server is called by a client. This causes a further call to be made to a 3rd party API. The API then asynchronously calls-back to the NodeJS server. How do I make the client aware that the asynchronous callback has completed?

**Details**

I have an NodeJS server with these two routes (code is coffeescript):

```
app.get '/security/login/application/authorise', -> 
    applicationService.authorise()

app.get '/security/login/application/callback', (req, res) -> 
    applicationService.login req, res
```

The first route is called by my AngularJS client. Its purpose is to authorise the client and allow it to start-up (users will sign in later). The authorisation process involves making a call to a third party security API.

The security API does its thing and then calls-back to the NodeJS server via the `/callback` route shown above. The information passed to the callback allows a further call to be made to the API that determines if the original authorisation request will pass or failed.

The problem is that call to the first call to the `/authorise` route is, of course, asynchronous and so returns to the client right away. The client is then left in limbo, not sure if the NodeJS server has authorised it or not.

Please note that I cannot just nest these calls (imo) because the first call to the API simply returns 200 OK regardless. The process only continues when, sometime in the future, the third party API starts a new conversation by calling back into the NodeJS server via the `/callback` route.

**Options**

It seems I have a number of unpalatable options:

1. Stay Asynchronous. Return control to the client and then have the client poll the server, presumably with some unique, temporary 'callback-id', to determine if the callback has been completed.
2. Go Synchronous. Block the return with a hacky loop of some sort. Maybe promises can clean this up a bit somehow.
3. Go Bidirectional. Use sockets to allow a push notification from the server (but what about old browsers like IE8, which I have to support).

I think I have probably over-cooked this problem and the solution is most likely easier than I imagine. Your help would be gratefully received.

Comment: This is a very frequent use case : you almost always have asynchronous tasks to do before you can answer a request. Simply send the response (using the `res` object you received) when you're ready, be it after a deep callback sequence or using promises.

Comment: Can you put up some code to illustrate please. I appreciate I am probably going to slap my head but I am still confused.

Comment: Look at the function starting [here](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs/auths.js#L17). It's answered after many db queries [here](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs/auths.js#L36). This code uses promises but you could do the same with standard callbacks.

Comment: The thing you might miss is that returning from the initial callback given to express does nothing. What's important is calling the functions on `res`.